# 301 Redirect from Wix to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, hashbang

A company I'm working for had a WIX based site. I recreated the site on WordPress moved the hosting and redirected the domain. I then attempted to do the page redirects to the new URLs on the WordPress site with the standard .httaccess file 301 redirects.

Redirect 301 /#!product/prd1/1063533171/42%22-workstation-(mc-42) http://www.mydomain.com/product/workstation/

I have now found that WIX uses a hashbang (#!) in the url link structure.

How can I execute my 301 redirects and retain my previous page rank?

Comment: for what I know you can't make 301 redirect from wix to other sites
here they have a thread where you can vote for this feature
http://www.wix.com/support/forum/html5/editor/other/customize-301-redirect

Comment: If what @Francisco Lavin says is true, then try uploading an index.php file to your wix root directory with some PHP code to execute the 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

i managed to redirect from wix to wordpress by adding this code (by Themee) to the functions.php on my theme directory.

```
function themee_hash_redirects() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function themee_hashtag_redirect( hashtag, url) {
            var locationHash = document.location.hash;
            if ( locationHash.match(/#!/img) ) {
                if ( hashtag == locationHash ) {
                    document.location.href = url;
                }
            }
        }
        // Examples how to use themee_hashtag_redirect
        themee_hashtag_redirect('#!dvd-content/c1yws', '/dvd-content/');
        themee_hashtag_redirect('#!krav-maga-shirts/c9r5', '/krav-maga-shirts/');
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'themee_hash_redirects');
```

as i understood, this only help to redirect your visitors to the correct URL, but not help to SEO.
i think the next code (in the .htaccess file) should help SEO, but still need some modification that i dont know about. this was an help by "barryhunter" from Google Forum.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=krav-maga-shirts/c9r5
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.972kravmaga.com/krav-maga-shirts [QSA,L]
```

its an example of one page redirect. the person who helped me said can check if its working on this page: http://www.rexswain.com

its will be nice if someone can determine what exactly should be written in the .htacess file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. The only solution I found is to create redirect.js file with the following content:

```
var hashesarr = { "#!about-us/c1it7":'/about-us/',
"#!patio-covers/ce54":'/patio-covers/',
"#!lattice/c1mz":'/patio-covers/lattice/' };

for (var hash in hashesarr) {
    var patt = new RegExp(hash);
    if (window.location.hash.match(patt) !== null) {
        window.location.href = hashesarr[hash];
    }
}
```

Then you should upload this file to your server and include it between `<head></head>` tags. This should do the trick.

Comment: Just an addition, if you place this script on your WIX website, then you need to change a part of your "for" loop to the following: `window.location.href = 'http://example.com'+hashesarr[hash];`

Answer (score 0):

Since wix URLs are hashtags, they cannot be redirected via .htaccess. You must use javascript to redirect urls, e.g.:

```
var redirects = {
    '#!about/c10fk':'about',
    '#!contact/c10fk':'contact',
    '#!help/c10fk':'help'
};

if(window.location.hash != '' && redirects.hasOwnProperty(window.location.hash)) {
    window.location.replace(redirects[window.location.hash]);
}
```