# WIX to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, web, velo

We have site that is based on wix. Now we have another site that has different host and different domain.

Is there any ability to create a redirect from wix page to wordpress page?

The problem is that wix doesn't allow to edit html code, so I can't have standard 301 redirect. I've read this [301 Redirect from Wix to WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608542/301-redirect-from-wix-to-wordpress) but didn't understand.

Is there any ability?

Tried to place in head `<meta http-equiv.....>` but wix blocks it. I can only add `<meta name.....>`.

Comment: You have the wrong "Wix". This WiX forum is for WiX the installation tool, not wix.com web hosting. I should delete the WiX tag. I don't believe there is a tag explicitly for "wix.com" web hosting.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your Wix site dashboard click on "**Marketing & SEO**" on the left hand side and then select "**SEO Tools**"

[image]

2. Select the "**URL Redirect Manager**" tab
3. Then select "**New Redirect**"
4. Enter the old URL and the new destination. If the destination is an external site start the URL with http:// or https://

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You want to permanently re-direct visitors from domain-a.com to domain-b.com, correct? But wix.com won't let you do it?

Dump wix.com and move the current domain-a.com domain to domain-b.com's hosting account then create an .htaccess file on domain-a.com to 301 permanently re-direct to domain-b.com