# redirect 301 with special character like WIX site “#!”

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, seo, permalinks

i want migrate a WIX website to wordpress and i want preserve the SEO score without broken the url of every post-page. but the structure of WIX url is composed by special character like "#!" , now how i can create a 301 that work.

the structure of wix url  is like this :

```
www.wix.com/#!this-is-a-test-page/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7
```

so i want redirect to a standard wordpress url example :

```
 www.wix.com/this-is-a-test-page/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7
```

now i tried a simple redirect 301 in htacess like this:

```
redirect 301 /#!this-is-a-test-page/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7 
www.wix.com/this-is-a-test-page2/a56730/821fa3180cf2779eabf1d2f7
```

but not work, how i can solve this ?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608542/301-redirect-from-wix-to-wordpress?rq=1

Comment: @Fencer04 yes, I realized that this problem goes beyond wordpress, so it is a problem that occurs on any web application, and de hard to find a solution

Comment: If you follow that link you'll find your answer. You can't use the htaccess file. You can use javascript or a custom function in wordpress.

Comment: @Fencer04  every trick with js found  are not good ,not preserve the SEO respect the 301 action